# WCF This could be due to the service endpoint binding not using the HTTP protocol

Tags: wcf, wcf-data-services, wcf-binding, httpresponse, json-deserialization

Default.aspx.cs

```
WCFService.Service1Client client = new WCFService.Service1Client();
string stream = client.JsonSerializeFromDatabase();
client.Close();
WCFService.Service1Client client2 = new WCFService.Service1Client();
foreach (WCFService.Person in client2.JsonDeserializeFromDatabase(stream))
```

Service1.svc.cs

```
public IList<Person> JsonDeserializeFromDatabase(string value)
{
    MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(value));
    DataContractJsonSerializer ser = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(List<Person>));
    IList<Person> tableData = (IList<Person>)ser.ReadObject(ms);
    ms.Close();
    ms.Dispose();

    return tableData;
}
```

IService1.cs

```
[OperationContract]
IList<Person> JsonDeserializeFromDatabase(string value);
```

Server Web.config

```
    <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="8192"/>
</system.web>
...
<system.serviceModel>
<services>
    <service name="TestWCF.Service1" behaviorConfiguration="TestWCF.Service1Behavior">
        <endpoint address="" binding="wsHttpBinding" contract="TestWCF.IService1">
            <identity>
                <dns value="localhost"/>
            </identity>
        </endpoint>
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
    </service>
</services>
<behaviors>
<serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="TestWCF.Service1Behavior">
    <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
    <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
    <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483646"/>
    </behavior>
</serviceBehaviors>
```

Client Web.config

```
    <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="8192"/>
</system.web>
<system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
        <endpointBehaviors>
            <behavior name="debuggingBehaviour">
                <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483646" />
            </behavior>
        </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <bindings>
        <wsHttpBinding>
            <binding name="WSHttpBinding_IService1" closeTimeout="00:50:00" openTimeout="00:50:00" receiveTimeout="00:50:00" sendTimeout="00:50:00" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" transactionFlow="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" useDefaultWebProxy="true" allowCookies="false">
            <readerQuotas maxDepth="64" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647"/>
            <reliableSession ordered="true" inactivityTimeout="00:50:00" enabled="false"/>
            <security mode="Message">
            <message clientCredentialType="Windows" negotiateServiceCredential="true" algorithmSuite="Default"/>
            </security>
        </binding>
    </wsHttpBinding>
</bindings>
<client>
    <endpoint address="~~~~~/Service1.svc" binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="WSHttpBinding_IService1" contract="WCFService.IService1" name="WSHttpBinding_IService1" behaviorConfiguration="debuggingBehaviour">
```

Exception Information
- Type: System.ServiceModel.CommunicationException, System.ServiceModel, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089
- Message: An error occurred while receiving the HTTP response to ~~~~~/Service1.svc. This could be due to the service endpoint binding not using the HTTP protocol. This could also be due to an HTTP request context being aborted by the server (possibly due to the service shutting down). See server logs for more details.

I got this exception information from Server trace viewer, so please do not advise me to put <-system.diagnostics-> tag.

As you can see, I increased all the size thing. 

Like.. i don't know why I am getting an error when I call JsonDeserializeFromDatabase(stream).
"An error occurred while receiving the HTTP response to ~~~~~/Service1.svc. This could be due to the service endpoint binding not using the HTTP protocol. This could also be due to an HTTP request context being aborted by the server (possibly due to the service shutting down). See server logs for more details."

Comment: Try to use byte[] for stream parameter (serialize/deserialize)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I too have experienced this error message when returning records from a database in a WCF service.  As well as increasing maxReceivedMessageSize in the binding in the client configuration (App.config), a separate problem seems to be that WCF has problems serializing Entity Framework objects if they have relationships that lead to circularity in their object graphs.

I solved this by returning buddy class objects (which are copies of the raw database records, but without any relationship links) rather than the raw database classes themselves.

Hope this helps -
And WHY doesn't Microsoft produce better error messages?? Here, as in many other cases, the error message gives no clue to the real problem (the serialization of the return value from the WCF call)!

Answer (score 3):

re: WCF & problems serializing Entity Framework objects if they have relationships that lead to circularity in their object graphs. I was getting the same error and the answer provided by user1956642 and it did point me in the right direction, but later realized I could serialize these entities by configuring the DbContext

```
context.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
```

Lazy loading is still enabled, but I believe the dynamic proxies are used for change tracking and lazy loading. So yea ... just my 5c